# How $y = mx+c $ satisfies Linear Transformation from $X $ to $Y$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, transformation

I was watching [3b1b](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE) video on linear transformations.

In that he said that linear transformations of matrices preserves origin from the original space to transformed space.

Now I got to prove this fact from the property of linearity:

$T(v+w)=T(v) + T(w) and T(cv) = cT(v)$
But then thinking of a straight line as linear transformation of $x$ to $y$ using $y=mx+c$

I think we call it a linear equation. And as transformation is a function really, thus the function $f(x)=mx+c$ is a linear function.

But I am not getting the property of linearity satisfied here.
For example,

$f(x) = mx+c$

when x=0, $f(0)= c$, thus O from original space is not mapped to 0 in transformed space.

Also, $f(0+5) = 5(x+0)+c = 5x+c $ but $f(0) + f(5) = c + 5x + c $.

Thus I am getting the linearity not satisfying. Is $y=mx+c$ not a linear transformation?

Thank you !

Comment: $mx+c$ is not a "linear function" in the linear algebra sense (unless $c=0$). It is sometimes called an "affine function" instead.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth oh! But we do call it linear equation? Isn't that same?

Comment: We generally call it "linear" because the graph is a straight line. But formally it is not a "linear function" in the linear algebra sense (since it will not satisfy the conditions of a linear function, as you showed).

Comment: ok! So, I thought earlier to call any equation linear, we need degree of variable to be 1. But now, the linearity property seems the dominant property! Then what we call homogeneous linear equations are in true sense 'linear equation' ?

Comment: "Linear" is a misleading term because it evoques a line and a line has equation $y=mx+c$. I confirm what has been said: in the framework of "Linear" (!) Algebra only $y=ax$ is called linear and $y=ax+b$ is always (not sometimes) called an affine application.

Comment: It really depends on context. In a Linear Algebra course, you would not call $f(x)=mx+c$ a linear function because it does not satisfy the conditions of a linear function. But in many other contexts it is fine to call it a linear function (and you will hear people doing so).

Comment: [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Over_the_real_numbers)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you! So, you say to preserve origin in both spaces, original and transformed, can we always have this need satisfied by using homogeneous equations, because then I think 0 in original space will map to 0 in transformed space and other linearity properties would be satisfied by degree of equation being 1 ?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Got it! its all relative! context is the key! Thank you so much !